# Star Wars fan film set during the Empire in which Jedi boy and girl kiss

Tags: story-identification, star-wars, fan-fiction

I remember a while ago I saw about 5 minutes of a *Star Wars* fan film that's older than *The Force Awakens* (it is from at least 7 years ago). All I remember from it is that it was set during the Empire (there were stormtroopers in it) and the main characters were a boy and girl who were in love. At the end of the movie they kiss and the boy says (paraphrased)

> We shouldn't have done that, I'm a Jedi and soon you will be too.

The boy had a blue lightsaber.

It was live action, I'm pretty sure it was on YouTube, and it was definitely not *Attack of the Clones*.

Comment: Do you remember anything about the length of this movie and whether it was live-action or animated?

Comment: No idea about the length, it was live action